# Is there an option to retrieve eclipse packages

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My eclipse files are lost .I opened eclipse page they show deferred early start  how to retrieve my files

I want to get my old package in eclipse
Please explain the process for retrieving my old package
Now I open eclipse page it will be opened new sheet, my old package are deleted